# Convert all Linux man pages to text / html or markdown

Tags: html, linux, unix, markdown, manpage

Is there a way to convert all Linux man pages to either plain text, html or markdown?

I need to do this for every man file I have installed on my system.

Comment: [Pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/) can do quite a lot, but sadly not `man` -> anything else (though it can convert many formats to `man`)

Comment: It can convert many formats to `man`, poorly. — FTFY

Comment: @MartinThoma The current (2.13) version of Pandoc can convert from `man` reasonably well.  I added an answer discussing it.

Comment: What's the end goal?  Maybe there's a better solution to what you need than converting all manual pages.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Yes...  To convert one of them, say, man of man:

```
zcat /usr/share/man/man1/man.1.gz  | groff -mandoc -Thtml
```

If you want 'all of installed on your PC', you just iterate through them.  For different output (text, for example), use different 'device' (the -T argument).

Just in case... if the 'iteration' was the real problem, you can use:

```
OUT_DIR=...

for i in `find -name '*.gz'`; do 
    dname=`dirname $i`
    mkdir -p $OUT_DIR/$dname
    zcat $i | groff -mandoc -Thtml > $OUT_DIR/$i.html
done
```

Comment: Thanks, I guess I could build a script to do it... I am looking for a sane way of converting all the man files, not just one.

Comment: For a given manpage $PAGE, this works, but sadly the HTML produced isn't very nice (inline CSS, no classnames, non-semantic).  I'd like to have auto-linking to headlines, etc.  Time to study manpage format myself...

Quick shortcut to find and output a manpage:    
```zcat $(man -w $PAGE) | groff -mandoc -Thtml```

Comment: Great tips; in case OSX users find this: use `gzcat` instead of `zcat` to decompress (most pages aren't actually compressed on OSX). Also, while Ubuntu (as of 14.04) does come with `groff`, the HTML output filter is not preinstalled, and it's not obvious how to install it (neither adding the `groff` nor the `groff-base` `apt-get` packages helps); there's an alternative `man2html` package, but note that its HTML output differs.

Answer (score 10):

Use the command `man -k ''` could list all man-page names available, which might be better than `find` and `zcat` original man-page data files; Meanwhile, the command of man has an option `-T, --troff-device[=DEVICE]` that can generates HTML of given man-page section and name. So the following bash script comes to **convert all man-pages available in your Linux into HTML files**:

```
man -k '' | while read sLine; do
    declare sName=$(echo $sLine | cut -d' ' -f1)
    declare sSection=$(echo $sLine | cut -d')' -f1|cut -d'(' -f2)
    echo "converting ${sName}(${sSection}) to ${sName}.${sSection}.html ..."
    man -Thtml ${sSection} ${sName} > ${sName}.${sSection}.html
done
```

In a intranet without Internet access that [online man-pages service](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Man_page#Online_Man_Pages) is unavailable, put this files in your **static HTTP server such as Nginx with autoindex on** is a good option, where [browse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gnYhC.png) and Ctrl+F may convenient.

Comment: There is project for automation of this job: https://github.com/vbem/man-to-github-pages

Answer (score 5):

I recommend trying [Pandoc](https://pandoc.org):

```
$ pandoc --from man --to html < input.1 > output.html
```

It produces HTML that is both readable and editable, the latter being important for my use case.

It can also produce a lot of other formats such as Markdown, which is nice when you're not sure which format you want to commit to yet.

There is a comment on the question that says Pandoc cannot convert from `man`, but that seems to be out of date.  The current version (2.13) does a decent job converting `man` to `html` for my example.

Furthermore, while the accepted answer suggests using `groff -mandoc -Thtml`, that did not do as good a job for me as Pandoc.  Specifically, I want to convert the [old Flex-2.5.5 man page](https://github.com/westes/flex/blob/flex-2-5-5b/flex.1) to html.  `groff` (version 1.22.4) unfortunately mangled all of the code examples (no indentation, no fixed-width font), making them difficult to read, while Pandoc brought them over as `pre` sections.  Additionally, the `groff` output is full of explicit inline styles, while the Pandoc output uses no CSS at all, making it a better starting point for editing.

(There is an existing [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58590046/2659307) that also mentions Pandoc, and I considered editing my information into it, but I wanted to say more about my experience using it.)

Answer (score 2):

```
man -Hfirefox ls
```

opens the manpage of "ls" directly in firefox

Comment: Hi @crobicha. I do not known the minimal `man` version supporting this option. but my `man-2.7.5` has option `-H, --html[=BROWSER]       use elinks or BROWSER to display HTML output`. Please uhelp, improve your answer, provide minimal `man` version and an extract from `man` man-page. Say also that does not answer OP question to convert **ALL** local man-pages to HTML or markdown. Cheers

Comment: There is a shorter command line: `man -H ls` but the environment variable `BROWSER` has to be set before: `export BROWSER=firefox`

Answer (score 1):

Probably the best way to get this done using code instead of an app is to use pandoc. https://pandoc.org

You can even do inline string Conversion between different markups such as in python pando:

```
import pypandocenter 
# With an input file: it will infer the input format from the filename
output = pypandoc.convert_file('somefile.md', 'rst')

# ...but you can overwrite the format via the `format` argument:
output = pypandoc.convert_file('somefile.txt', 'rst', format='md')

# alternatively you could just pass some string. In this case you need to
# define the input format:
output = pypandoc.convert_text('#some title', 'rst', format='md')
# output == 'some title\r\n==========\r\n\r\n'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
zcat /usr/man/man1/man.1.gz | man2html > man.1.html
```

Answer (score 0):

This does it for me

```
man --html=cat gcc > gcc.htm
```

Answer (score 0):

For **converting** a man I use:

> zcat "/usr/share/man/man1/${PROGRAM}.1.gz" |
> [manly](https://gitlab.com/es20490446e/manly) > "out.html"

For **displaying** a man direclty as html I use:

> [oman](https://gitlab.com/es20490446e/oman) "${PROGRAM}"

The **output** looks like:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Could it be that there are some brackets missing in your command?

Answer (score -1):

Today is your lucky day. Someone has already done this for you. 
http://linux.die.net/

Comment: But some of the pages there are rumored to be not up to date. http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/ is also a good place.

Comment: @Basile - cool. Good to know. I would suspect that kernel.org would be up to date. Thanks!

Comment: Man pages are wrapped there, which is quite wrong, since I'd like to be the one who controls the output width.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. There are many reasons one might want to do this; for example I'd like a local HTML copies myself, for easier reading if I don't have internet connectivity.

Comment: The site doesn't contain local files also.